# How to make faster UI updation in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have a table for showing production forecasting for user selected range of date. The table consists of 
40 columns and around 1000 rows.

I have made some columns editable for making changes to the plan. This change will be reported in server using ajax and json[which property and what is the value]. The server will recalculate and change in table values are reported back to client in json format [column no, rowno,value].

I iterate through the json array and  update the table like

```
$("#GridViewPlan tr:eq(" + (myRow) + ") td:eq(" + myCol + ")").text(val);
```

But my problem is the above sentence in for loop (ui updation) is taking time

How can I improve this architecture ? Is there anything like jquery library for Quick UI updation

Comment: Have you had a look with eg [Dynatrace AJAX Edition](https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/AJAX/Dynatrace+AJAX+Edition+Community+Home), which is a good diagnosis tool ...

Comment: Are you returning the full contnent of the grid for refreshing? if so, can you do some tweaks at the server and try returing only if there is a change. In that case you need to refresh only the updated values.

Comment: Am reporting back only the changes. Suppose there is 1000 changes
Then thousand UI updation is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) another javascript library that uses [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained) pattern. it will make you data binding easy and faster. For more information please read the [official documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html)
And the cool thing is you can use jQuery and KnockoutJS simultaneously. For tables with large numbers of record you may want to enable paging like this:

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>

<button data-bind='click: addItem'>
    Add item
</button>

<button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
    Sort by name
</button>

<button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
    Jump to first page
</button>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
    var initialData = [
        { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
        { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
        { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
        { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
        { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
        { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
        { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
    ];

    var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

        this.addItem = function() {
            this.items.push({ name: "New item", sales: 0, price: 100 });
        };

        this.sortByName = function() {
            this.items.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1;
            });
        };

        this.jumpToFirstPage = function() {
            this.gridViewModel.currentPageIndex(0);
        };

        this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
            data: this.items,
            columns: [
                { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
                { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales" },
                { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
            ],
            pageSize: 4
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
</script>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/)